# xpages horizontal slider throwing a javascript error

Tags: javascript, dojo, slider, xpages

When I move the slider the first time this pops up

> An error occurred while updating some of the page. document1 is undefined.

I have used the dojo slider often and have never run into this. `document1` is the correct name of the data source.
The slider writes to a field and the value is actually saved correctly. Everything is working but why am I getting this error?

```
<xe:djHorizontalSlider id="djHorizontalSlider7"
                value="#{viewScope.sliderNumber7}"
                style="margin: 5px;width:480px; height:20px;" minimum="0"
                maximum="100" discreteValues="101" showButtons="false">

                <xe:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.getItemValueInteger("Burns_Pct")}]]></xe:this.defaultValue>

                <xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:convertNumber integerOnly="true">
                    </xp:convertNumber>
                </xp:this.converter>
                <xe:djSliderRule id="djSliderRule7"
                    style="height:5px;" count="3" container="bottomDecoration">
                </xe:djSliderRule>
                <xe:djSliderRuleLabels id="djSliderRuleLabels7"
                    container="bottomDecoration"
                    style="height:10px;font-size:100%;color:black;">
                    <li>
                        0 Percent
                    </li>
                    <li></li>
                    <li>
                        100 Percent
                    </li>
                </xe:djSliderRuleLabels>
                <xp:eventHandler event="onChange" submit="true"
                    refreshMode="partial" refreshId="Burns_Pct">
                    <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
viewScope.inputNumber7 = viewScope.sliderNumber7
        }]]></xe:this.action>


                </xp:eventHandler>
            </xe:djHorizontalSlider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer after trying for a couple of days.

I had script in the xpage `onClientLoad` section when it should have been in the `beforePageLoad`.

The purpose of this was to make sure the slider goes to the correct place if the user navigates between pages of survey. So, I am grabbing the value of the stored text box on `document1` and assigning the slider control the value when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

We can't see your document definition on the page but I assume it's simply not the correct name of your data source.